# Каким образом реализовать сжатие bzip2 на php?

Tags: php

при сжатии bzip2

```php
$str = "sample data";
$bzstr = bzcompress($str, 9);
echo $bzstr;
```

выдаёт такую строку: BZh91AY&SY�?���@&L "�� Ɉ�-�.�p�!�0�

Используя сервис
http://www.txtwizard.net/compression получаем строку: 
QlpoOTFBWSZTWdIYP8MAAASRgEAAJgZMACAAMQZMQQDTamMW8MqPF3JFOFCQ0hg/ww==

Каким образом можно реализовать похожий результат.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: спасибо, обернул в base64 дополнительно и сработало, но всё это делается ради сжатия данных, надеюсь сработает

Comment: base64 ухудшает сжатие, зачем он тут нужен - непонятно. Если вы бездумно повторяете за онлайн-сервисами, то не надо так делать

Comment: нет, так нужно, всё в порядке